# How to create manual paper size

Tags: printing

I like to create custom page size to print in my printer , connected in ubuntu.l like to create 7inch width and 3 inch height. How it possible.

Answer (score 1):

Set up your printer through the CUPS interface, `http://localhost:631/admin`. As you do this, you can select all sorts of printer configuration options. Also read `man lpoptions;man lpadmin`, and if you want more, start with `man -k CUPS`.

I have three CUPS "queues" set up, all pointing to the same physical printer, to let me print on `8 1/2 x 11`, `Env10` envelopes, or type `8163` labels. In the past, I've also set up printing to `A4` paper, 3-hole 8 1/2 x 11.

Here's what my `lpoptions -l` output for each of my current queues (all current values are listed, an initial `*` marks the currently selected value) (note the paper type "`Custom.WIDTHxHEIGHT`". I assume `WIDTH` and `HEIGHT` are in inches, based on other paper types)):

```
$ for i in $( lpstat -a | awk '{print $1}' ) ; do 
> echo -e "\t\tprinter $i"
> lpoptions -p $i -l | grep '\*'
> echo
> done
        printer deskjet
PageSize/Media Size: Card3x5 Card3x5.FB Hagaki.SM Hagaki.FB Hagaki Photo4x6 Photo4x6.FB A6.SM A6.FB A6 Photo5x7 Photo5x7.FB Card5x8.SM Card5x8 Oufuku.SM Oufuku.FB Oufuku A5.SM A5.FB A5 B5.SM B5 JB5.SM JB5.FB JB5 Executive.SM Executive 16k 8x10 *Letter.SM Letter.FB Letter A4.SM A4.FB A4 ExecutiveJIS FLSA Legal.SM Legal CDDVD80 CDDVD120 EnvA2 EnvC6 EnvChou4 EnvMonarch EnvDL Env10 EnvChou3 EnvC5 EnvB5 Custom.WIDTHxHEIGHT
Duplex/Double-Sided Printing: *DuplexNoTumble DuplexTumble None
InputSlot/Media Source: *Auto PhotoTray Upper Lower Envelope LargeCapacity Manual MPTray CDDVDTray
ColorModel/Output Mode: CMYGray KGray *RGB
MediaType/Media Type: *Automatic Plain Glossy TransparencyFilm CDDVDMedia
OutputMode/Print Quality: *Normal Draft Best Photo FastDraft
OptionDuplex/Duplexer Installed: False *True

        printer envelope
PageSize/Media Size: Card3x5 Card3x5.FB Hagaki.SM Hagaki.FB Hagaki Photo4x6 Photo4x6.FB A6.SM A6.FB A6 Photo5x7 Photo5x7.FB Card5x8.SM Card5x8 Oufuku.SM Oufuku.FB Oufuku A5.SM A5.FB A5 B5.SM B5 JB5.SM JB5.FB JB5 Executive.SM Executive 16k 8x10 Letter.SM Letter.FB Letter A4.SM A4.FB A4 ExecutiveJIS FLSA Legal.SM Legal CDDVD80 CDDVD120 EnvA2 EnvC6 EnvChou4 EnvMonarch EnvDL *Env10 EnvChou3 EnvC5 EnvB5 Custom.WIDTHxHEIGHT
Duplex/Double-Sided Printing: DuplexNoTumble DuplexTumble *None
InputSlot/Media Source: *Auto PhotoTray Upper Lower Envelope LargeCapacity Manual MPTray CDDVDTray
ColorModel/Output Mode: CMYGray KGray *RGB
MediaType/Media Type: *Automatic Plain Glossy TransparencyFilm CDDVDMedia
OutputMode/Print Quality: Normal Draft *Best Photo FastDraft
OptionDuplex/Duplexer Installed: *False True

        printer Labels8163
PageSize/Media Size: Card3x5 Card3x5.FB Hagaki.SM Hagaki.FB Hagaki Photo4x6 Photo4x6.FB A6.SM A6.FB A6 Photo5x7 Photo5x7.FB Card5x8.SM Card5x8 Oufuku.SM Oufuku.FB Oufuku A5.SM A5.FB A5 B5.SM B5 JB5.SM JB5.FB JB5 Executive.SM Executive 16k 8x10 Letter.SM *Letter.FB Letter A4.SM A4.FB A4 ExecutiveJIS FLSA Legal.SM Legal CDDVD80 CDDVD120 EnvA2 EnvC6 EnvChou4 EnvMonarch EnvDL Env10 EnvChou3 EnvC5 EnvB5 Custom.WIDTHxHEIGHT
Duplex/Double-Sided Printing: DuplexNoTumble DuplexTumble *None
InputSlot/Media Source: *Auto PhotoTray Upper Lower Envelope LargeCapacity Manual MPTray CDDVDTray
ColorModel/Output Mode: CMYGray KGray *RGB
MediaType/Media Type: *Automatic Plain Glossy TransparencyFilm CDDVDMedia
OutputMode/Print Quality: Normal Draft *Best Photo FastDraft
OptionDuplex/Duplexer Installed: False *True
```